# Overriding Android setDataSource in MyMediaPlayer

Tags: android

I want to implement my own MediaPlayer on the basis of android MediaPlayer but i want to override its functions like setDataSource.

From the java application i will call say setPlayerSource("mp4file").setPlayerSource should be implemented in MyMediaPlayer class which inherits from android MediaPlayerBase.In MyMediaPlayer i will just create an object for StageFrightPlayer and create its instance.
And then i will call android prepare and start function to use all the functionality of AwesomePlayer to play my mp4 file.Is it possible to do this.Are there any shortcomings in my approach.Later on i want to customise my MyMediaPlayer so that it uses only OMX hardware codec component for decoding.

Since i have inherited from MediaPlayerBase is it necessary to provide definition of all the 
functions in derived class since MediaPlayerBase is an abstract base class.Is there any workaround in this.

Please guide how i can proceed doing this.

Regards
Mayank